Formula based Data Validation in Excel Web sheets
This is a follow up from this post. If cell A2 is empty and a value is being entered in cell B2, I want a dialog box to prompt entry in cell A2
I tried the method suggested by the contributor in desktop excel and it works perfectly:

However when I do the same for an excel sheet on the web, it doesnt seem to work. No validations take place whether cell A2 is empty or not.
However, if I remove the = sign in the formula, the dialog box does pop up, but even when cell A2 is not blank.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated!

This looks like an Excel bug.
But you can use another formula that works for me:
=COUNTIF($A$2,"?*")


Did you try using =NOT(ISBLANK)) and it dint work for you?

I tried both =NOT(ISBLANK)) and =LEN()>0. They don't work.

Thank you for checking. I guess we need to submit this as a bug to microsoft. Not that they will do anything about it.
Your COUNTIF formula worked. Thanks again!
